# Getting a web part HTML id, in a web part page, using javascript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I have a web part page with four web parts:

1 Content editor - to run some javascript.

2 Infopath form web parts.

1 list view web part.

I want to change the display properties of those web parts dynamically according to what happenes on page (specific list connection or user actions)

For that, i need to know which web part's html id (they are registered as WebPartWPQ2, WebPartWPQ3 and so on..)is which, and what the id's are in the first place.

I tried using WPSC(Web Part Page Services Component) but it seems to only register the content editor W.P on the page - and disregards the list view or the infopath form web parts.

Trying the ECMAscript client object model (SP.Webparts is what i tried using) got me the web parts on the page, but no option to get the actual html id (just the GUID)

does anyone have an idea as to how to get the id's for the web parts?

- i want to eventually be able to edit this page, so i can assume with confident that those ids will change.

Answer (score 0):

Get up the Toolpart (Modify Shared Web Part) then Right Click > View Source.

Do a search for

```
MSOSPWebPartManager_OldSelectedStorageKeyName
```

and there is the ID of your web part `(Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart.ID)`

Tested with WSS3 (SharePoint 2007) and SharePoint Foundation 2010.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, but as i'm planning to save this site as a template, i'll need some way to get those html id's on the fly, as they change every time a web part is added or removed.